# Can't detect locations in AS3 using compare operators

Tags: actionscript-3, if-statement

I have made 5 "endzones" on the top of the screen except they aren't being detected at all. After the zone is taken, it is locked out.

The functions like safeX() make the xsafe variable equal to 1 so they will stop working after they are taken, but only last row is tracing. They are predetermined locations so it should be working, but it always skips to the last "else". I have no idea what to change about this code, it works elsewhere in the program but not here:

```
if (-5 > man.x && man.x > 25) {
    if (onesafe == 0) {
        safeOne();
        trace("1 done")
    } else {
        deadMan();
        trace("1 full")
    }
} else if (55 > man.x && man.x > 85) {
    if (twosafe == 0) {
        safeTwo();
        trace("2 done")
    } else {
        deadMan();
        trace("2 full")
    }
} else if (115 > man.x && man.x > 145) {
    if (threesafe == 0) {
        safeThree();
        trace("3 done")
    } else {
        deadMan();
        trace("3 full")
    }
} else if (175 > man.x && man.x > 205) {
    if (foursafe == 0) {
        safeFour();
        trace("4 done")
    } else {
        deadMan();
        trace("4 full")
    }
} else if (235 > man.x && man.x > 265) {
    if (fivesafe == 0) {
        safeFive();
        trace("5 done")
    } else {
        deadMan();
        trace("5 full")
    }
} else {
    deadMan();
    trace("last row");
}
```

This is in Action Script 3

Comment: What language is this...?

Comment: Action Script 3, I wrote AS3 in the question title

Comment: It's worth tagging it as such, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It skips to the last `else` because all of the conditions are impossible. I think you have some of your `>` and `<` signs backwards.

For example, in the first `if`, you check if `-5 > man.x`, or if `man.x` is *less than* `-5`. You then check if `man.x > 25`. This variable cannot be less than -5 and greater than 25 at the same time.

Perhaps you meant to say `if (-5 < man.x && man.x < 25)`.

A clearer way to write this would be `if (man.x > -5 && man.x < 25)`. It makes it easier to see errors such as this when you put the variable before the constant in a comparison.

Comment: Oh that explains it... I copied the code from another part of the program but I didnt bother checking the numbers after I changed them... Thanks for your help.

Comment: I thought I had that correct though, I guess it confused me too much and I got the signs mixed up